# Meson Fails To Compile Code Properly, How Do I Fix It?

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, ninja, meson-build

I'm trying to compile this program called ahowviewer from sources Github, not the release. The problems have to do with the two dependencies, libunrar and libnsgif. For libunrar, I needed a .pc file for it be found by the compiler. Whenever I do generate the file it terminates the compilation at the end with the error message `src/meson.build:98:5: ERROR: Unknown variable "libunrar_dll_hpp".` and nothing else to help me debug. When I do remove it though, it detects the dll.hpp file, the library, but not the runtime dependency. It has something to do with the variable being assigned a value, depending on an if statement. Don't know much else besides that.

The other problem is that when I remove the .pc file, cd into build and run ninja, this error message pops up

`./src/archive/../image.h:8:10: fatal error: libnsgif.h: No such file or directory   8 | #include <libnsgif.h>   |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated."`

```
What's my problem here?
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [meson.build's snippet](https://github.com/ahodesuka/ahoviewer/blob/master/src/meson.build#L165), this project can use own "external" version of libnsgif (and it looks it's preferred way?).  So, after you uninstall package (purge) so that this dependency can't be found, just reconfigure the build directory:

```
$ meson --reconfigure build_dir/
```

With libunrar you have another problem. It's a non-free package and doesn't provide .pc file (.pc, a.k.a package config file is not for compiler, in short, it's a text file of key/value format that tells where library, header is located). You shouldn't create .pc file for it yourself as this project doesn't expect it to be found! If you need it - meson should be able to find library (if it can't - it's different question), but since it's not a requirement, this project can be configured without it (check [options](https://github.com/ahodesuka/ahoviewer/blob/master/meson_options.txt)):

```
$ meson configure build_dir/ -Dlibunrar=false
```